# Euler-Lagrange equations for hydrogen atoms

Tags: integration, physics, quantum-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

This is the expression for the energy of the hydrogen atom, which can be expressed as the following integral

$$ E = \int \psi^* \cdot \hat{H} \cdot \psi d \tau \\
\hat{H}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2 m_e r^2} \frac{d}{d r}\left(r^2 \frac{d}{d r}\right)-\frac{e^2}{4 \pi \varepsilon_0} $$

where $\hbar$, $m_e$ and $\epsilon$ are known variables and $\psi^*$ is the conjugate transpose of $\psi$. We can think of this as $f$ in the Euler-Lagrangian quantity:

$$ \psi^* \cdot \hat{H} \cdot \psi $$

If I plug $\hat{H}$ in, I get:

$$ f\left(r,\psi, \frac{d\psi}{dr}\right)=\psi^* \cdot \frac{1}{r^2} \frac{d}{d r}\left(r^2 \frac{d \psi}{d r}\right)-\psi^*\frac{e^2}{4 \pi \varepsilon r} \cdot \psi $$

And then I can plug $f$ into the Euler-Lagrange equation,Now the question is, I don't know how to plug it in, because it has a second derivative and $\psi^*$, right

---

According to the comments, the Euler-Lagrange formula of the second derivative is required, I asked ChatGPT

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial \psi}-\frac{d}{d r}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\left(\partial_r \psi\right)}\right)+\frac{d^2}{d r^2}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial\left(\partial_r^2 \psi\right)}\right) = 0 $$

I'm not going to deal with $psi^*$, but I'm going to assume $psi^*$ is a real function,So here's how I do it

[image]

[image]

[image]

Am I doing the right things?

Comment: You'll need to use a higher order Euler-Lagrange equation due to the second derivative that appears

Comment: @Lorago I don't see the second order formula in Wikipedia and I don't know what to do with it, and $\psi^*$, right

Comment: Th Euler-Lagrange is a derived relationship from taking $L_{\Psi+\epsilon} - L_{\Psi}$ and extremizing this difference. For non-standard looking equations, it imight be more reassuring to start from $L_{\Psi+\epsilon} - L_{\Psi}$ and see if you can get it to a form where the functional $\epsilon$ vanish for a certain expression. This expression is automatically the Euler-Lagrange equation for this L.

Comment: @James Do you have any problems with my procedure, and how do I deal with $\psi^*$

Comment: i have seen the derivation for hydrogen atom some time back, but i can't remember it anymore. I think there is a long chapter covering the steps in detail in Griffith "Intro to QM"

Comment: @James I've read this book, and I know the solution, the Euler-Lagrange equation that I'm using here, and I don't see any books that use it, so I want to try it

Comment: I get something very similar to what you got.

Comment: Look like you are missing the term $\frac{h^2}{2m_e}$ in the Lagrangian.

Comment: @ArcticChar oh,yes,you are right

Answer (score 1):

$$L_{\Psi+\epsilon} = (\frac{\bar \Psi + \bar \epsilon}{r^2})\frac{d}{dr}(r^2\frac{d(\Psi + \epsilon)}{dt}) - \frac{e^2(\bar \Psi + \bar \epsilon)}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}(\Psi + \epsilon)$$

$$L_{\Psi} = \frac{\bar \Psi}{r^2}\frac{d}{dr}(r^2\frac{d\Psi}{dt}) - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\bar \Psi\Psi$$

Then,

$$L_{\Psi+\epsilon} - L_{\Psi} = \bar \epsilon\frac{d^2\Psi}{dr^2} + \frac{2}{r}\bar \epsilon \frac{d\Psi}{dr} + \bar \epsilon\frac{d^2\epsilon}{dr^2} + \frac{2}{r}\bar\Psi \frac{d\epsilon}{dr} + \frac{2}{r}\bar\epsilon\frac{d\epsilon}{dr}-\frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}\epsilon$$

$$=\bar \epsilon (\frac{d^2\Psi}{dr^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{d\Psi}{dr} - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r}) + \bar \epsilon \frac{d^2\epsilon}{dr^2} + \Psi\frac{d^2\epsilon}{dr^2} + \frac{2}{r}\bar\Psi\frac{d\epsilon}{dr}$$

Suppose that all terms involving $\frac{d\epsilon}{dr}$ and higher derivatives vanish, then

$$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dr^2} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{d\Psi}{dr} - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0r} = 0$$

is the Euler-Lagrange equation, as it will make the first term vanish as well, giving $L_{\Psi+\epsilon} - L_{\Psi}=0$ which is an extremum of L over arbitrary functionals.

Comment: Why do you use $\epsilon$ instead of the derivative form

Comment: The part to show the higher order terms go to zero might need more work i think, because there is $\epsilon$ and there is $\bar \epsilon$... Sometimes guessing an integration by parts and rearranging the result gets to put the higher terms into a form that definitely goes to zero.